# Do the armies of the Asuras and Rakshasas ally with the Mleccha kingdoms in their attacks on the Vedic civilization?

Tags: asuras, rakshasa, evil, mleccha

The Asuras and Rakshasas have a knack for destroying the Earth, the Vedic civilization, and the members of the 4 castes.

Do the armies of the Asuras and Rakshasas form alliances with the Mleccha kingdoms in their attacks on the Vedic civilization?

For example, here is what Hiranyakashipu did in his invasion of Earth, from chapter 2, canto 7 of the *Bhagavata Purana*:

[image]
[image]
[image]